# Continuous deployment on Azure webapp suddenly failing

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

I am using a link webapp service on azure to deploy a node.js app, with continuous deployment config (plugged to a bitbucket repo)

It was sync all fine for a month, and yesterday was working all fine....

and out of the SUDDEN, it is getting that error, the last push was just an html fixing :

> Command: kudusync -v 50 -f /home/site/repository -t /home/site/wwwroot
>   -n /home/site/deployments/66eb1a0473cf46c9c6d86623ad0df748755599d1/manifest
>   -p /home/site/deployments/2ca9e0bcac1e9c1744862af68b68354883e38d7d/manifest
>   -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;.deploy.sh" Kudu sync from: '/home/site/repository' to: '/home/site/wwwroot' Error: ENOENT: no
>   such file or directory, stat '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules'
>   \n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh kudusync -v 50 -f /home/site/repository
>   -t /home/site/wwwroot -n /home/site/deployments/66eb1a0473cf46c9c6d86623ad0df748755599d1/manifest
>   -p /home/site/deployments/2ca9e0bcac1e9c1744862af68b68354883e38d7d/manifest
>   -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;.deploy.sh

I have searched a lot about this error but all threads are old and not relevant anymore.

Help? How is that possible that a such error occurs why nothing at all got changed in azure's config nor in the app code itself.

Comment: suspecting that this issue is related to kudusync with particular version(s) of nodejs when deploying from github. I am checking internally and trying to repro. Will update you

Comment: my webapp is on node.js 14.0